# Trouble with Android TabHost

Tags: android, tabs

I want to creat my tab host programmaticly, as it seems I can't add icons otherwise? Anyways... This is how I do it. I get an error when trying to use the tabHost.addTab() function.

```
private void setupTabs() {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "Starting tab setup");
    createTab("Hjem", R.drawable.ic_menu_home, HomeActivity.class);
    createTab("Nyheter", R.drawable.ic_menu_home, HomeActivity.class);
    createTab("Podcast", R.drawable.ic_menu_home, HomeActivity.class);
    Log.d("DEBUG", "Finished tab setup");
}

private void createTab(String label, int drawableId, Class<?> activity) {
    //Create tab
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + label);

    //Set indicator
    Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, drawableId);
    spec.setIndicator(label, image);

    //Set content
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity);
    spec.setContent(intent);

    //Add tab
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some more searches and managed to figure it out.
I primarily did 3 changes.

1. Change the id of my designer tab to @android:id/tabhost
2. Change the activity to extends TabActivity
3. Add tabHost.setup() after grabbing the refrence to tabHost

Comment: TabActivity was deprecated long ago.  You really should switch to using a TabLayout. See here: https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout